# Sql query returning int instead of decimals

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sum

Working on a sql query, but found out that Sum does not like decimals, thats why decimals values (XX,XX) becomes integer. My database is build up with routines connected with measure_routine as pivot table and measurement.

SQL:

```
SELECT routines.date, routines.time, SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Badende_per_Time', routines.value, 0 ) ) AS T_Badende_per_Time,
                                     SUM(IF(measurements.title = 'T_Temperatur', routines.value, 0)) AS T_Temperatur
FROM routines
INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;
```

[image]

Database:

[image]

Comment: Er... sum doesn't like decimals? In what way?

Comment: Thanks for the status report. What you say you found misrepresents MySQL operations. Test cases easily demonstrate that the SUM aggregate function operates on DECIMAL values just fine. Did you have a question?

Comment: Interesting, then I am very unsure why my sql query is not returning the decimals. The other think is that if I change comma to dot, I get the value out.

Comment: I suggest you try a simple test case. Create table with a column of datatype DECIMAL, populate a few rows, and run a query that returns a SUM() of that column.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a question?

Most likely explanation for the behavior you observe is implicit datatype conversions. You don't provide enough information about the datatypes of the columns, and the contents of the rows, to determine that.

If your `value` column is character datatype (e.g. CHAR or VARCHAR), you probably want to use the `CAST` or `CONVERT` function to convert that to a `DECIMAL` type, and then perform the SUM on that.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

```
SELECT CAST('30.95' AS DECIMAL(20,2)) 
     , CONVERT('30.95',DECIMAL(20,2))
```

A simple test case demonstrates that the SQL `SUM()` aggregate function operates on DECIMAL datatype values just fine.

Were you asking a question?

---

**UPDATE**

It appears that the SUM aggregate in your query is not operating on a DECIMAL datatype, you've specified `SUM` on VARCHAR data. So, MySQL is performing an implicit data conversion to numeric data.

I think REAL question to be asked is why decimal values are being stored as character datatype.

To convert character strings as values to DECIMAL, interpreting a comma character as a decimal point, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT r.date
     , r.time
     , SUM(IF(m.title = 'T_Badende_per_Time'
       ,CONVERT(REPLACE(r.value,',','.'),DECIMAL(20,2))
       ,0)) AS T_Badende_per_Time
     , SUM(IF(m.title = 'T_Temperatur'
       ,CONVERT(REPLACE(r.value,',','.'),DECIMAL(20,2))
       ,0)) AS T_Temperatur
  FROM routines r
  JOIN measure_routine mr 
    ON mr.routine_id = r.id
  JOIN measurements m 
    ON m.id = mr.measure_id
 GROUP BY r.date, r.time
```

Comment: Is it me or should the output be with comma?: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h04z5twtauv6eee/test.png

Comment: @user3185963: I believe MySQL always uses the dot character (`.`) as the decimal separator; I don't believe there is any way to change that in MySQL. (But you might find otherwise; I'm not an authority on that. I think the MySQL approach is that locale settings for display are applied at the presentation layer of the application; the database uses a single standard. I know that MySQL doesn't like thousands separators; I have to remove those with expressions when I do a `LOAD DATA` from text, and need to convert from string to numeric.

Comment: @user3185963: If you need the decimal separator dot character replaced with a comma character, you could cast/convert the result from the `SUM(expr)` back into a string, and do the required replacement using the REPLACE function, e.g. "`REPLACE( SUM(expr) ,'.',',') AS`". Again, we wouldn't normally do that, we'd let the database return what it returns from the SQL SUM, and we'd handle any formatting for display in the presentation layer.